# How to make dataframe in pandas as numeric?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am learning the book Python for Data Analysis, after running the code from the book I got a pandas dataframe diversity like this:

> sex  F  M
>
> year
>
> 1880 [38] [14]
>
> 1881 [38] [14]

When I want to use diversity.plot() to draw some pictures, there is TypeError:

Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

So, my question is how to deal with this dataframe to make it as numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a list of int in your data frame. To convert it to you need to select the value inside and form data frame.

I suggest you this code to convert

> `for col in df:
>      df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem, sorry I cannot vote up now, I will be back to vote up you when I am capable.